# Creating a changing sequence of numbers in a for loop Java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to increment the following sequence in a for loop (Java):

1, 4, 9, 16, 25 etc the difference increasing by two each time. I tried using 'i+=3 + i' but I know that's wrong since it doesn't take into account that the variable i changes along the sequence.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: `i += 3 + i` would give `i = 3 + i + i` kind of 1, 5, 13 ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `i` is changing, the simple logic is, use another variable that is declared outside the scope of the loop. This will make sure that it is not recreated everytime the loop runs.

```
int num = 1;
for(int i=1; i<maxValue; num+=2,i+=num){
    //Use the value of `i` here, it will be as you wanted. 
}
```

Comment: That looks like C++ to me, the OP is using Java

Comment: That souldn't make make much difference though. Made appropriate changes.  Thank you for pointing that out. @MrWiggles

Comment: Thanks! It's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could have an increment of `i+=k` and change `k` inside the loop in order to change the increment.

```
int k=1;
for (int i=1;i<1000;i+=k) {
   k+=2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work! I was thinking about creating another variable but wasn't sure how to go about it. It's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is to start with j=1 and k=4 and then derive next values of the series n times. The formula as follow:

```
Initial loop (i=0): 
j = 1, k = 4; 

Loop (i > 0 less than n):
Repeat below n times: 
temp = k; 
k = k + (k - j + 2); 
j = temp;
print value of j being the series;
```

I assume that you take n as input from user and then generate the series nth times. Let's look at the following code example

```
int n = 10;  
for(int i = 0, temp = 0, j = 1, k = 4; i < n; i++, temp = k, k += (k-j+2), j = temp) {
   System.out.println(j);
}
```

Assuming that user inputs n = 10, the loop initializes i = 0 and continues until i < n is satisfied. It initializes j = 1 and k = 4 and then execute the body of the loop (printing j) followed by backing up the value of k, calculating new value for k and replacing the old value of j. The output for n = 10 is as follow:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Series number from the user and generate series based on given number.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int ans;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  ans = i * i;
  System.out.println(ans);
}
```